# Find device.description of default sink from pulseaudio

Tags: command-line, pulseaudio, text-processing

Running `pacmd list-sinks | grep -e "index" -e "device.description"` outputs:

```
  index: 0
    device.description = "GP106 High Definition Audio Controller Digital Stereo (HDMI)"
  index: 1
    device.description = "Built-in Audio Analog Stereo"
* index: 2
    device.description = "HD 4.40BT"
```

The default sink starts with `* index:`. In the above example I want to output `HD 4.40BT`.

So the problem-statement is: match `* index` and then output the next `device.description` that is matched. How can I do that using `grep` or `sed` or `awk`?

**EDIT:** May be starting with `pacmd list-sinks` is the wrong place to start. Is there a better command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have something hacky that works:

```
pacmd list-sinks | grep -Pzo "\* index(.*\n)*" | sed \$d | grep -e "device.description" | cut -f2 -d\"
```

Explanation:

1. `grep -Pzo "\* index(.*\n)*"` outputs all lines after matching `* index`.
2. The last line on the output was causing problems. Removed it with `sed \$d`.
3. `grep -e "device.description"` matches the first `device.description`.
4. And lastly `cut -f2 -d\"` to output only the content.

Comment: This solution would output multiple `device.description`s for me if the default sink wasn't last in the list of sinks. A revised version I'm using looks like: `pacmd list-sinks | grep -e "index" -e "device.description" | grep -A1 '*' | tail -n1 | cut -f2 -d\"`

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to get the device name, which we can do like this:

```
# pactl get-default-sink
alsa_output.pci-0000_28_00.4.analog-stereo
```

To get the description, I have a slight variation on the accepted answer, using sed rather than grep to extract the rest of the file following the `* index` line, which marks the default sink.

```
# pacmd list-sinks | sed -n '/^\s*\* index/,$p' | grep '^\s*device.description =' | cut -f2 -d\"
Starship/Matisse HD Audio Controller Analog Stereo
```